# Sending input to a single running script from multiple sources simultaneously

Tags: python, linux, bash, raspberry-pi, cgi

Here is **what i have done, successfully**.

I have Python code that launches an external program (for example omxplayer) using Popen:

```
 player = Popen(["omxplayer",file_name],stdin=PIPE)
```

Works fine.

Depending upon some user inputs, I am also able to control the behaviour by using Popen.communicate from elsewhere in the program:

```
 player.communicate("q")
```

Works fine too.

Next, I also have a web interface (in CGI and .sh) where the same is accomplished by remotely logging in, and using named pipes:

```
/usr/bin/omxplayer "$1" < /tmp/cmd
```

And also send communication to the player using:

```
echo -n q > /tmp/cmd
```

Now my **question**, is there a way to get the CGI or shell scripts to interact (send communication / message / keystrokes) to the same program that was launched via the Python code? 
So basically, I'm trying to connect to the program launched from Python locally, using a web page in CGI. Is it doable?

I was thinking if I could add the named pipe (like < /tmp/cmd) to the launcher (in Python) then maybe from the CGI script I will just use the same logic and echo to the pipe. Is that the right way to do it?

Any clues what I could do, if it is possible?

Comment: I seems to work with php, so It sould work with bash too. Problem is that I dont use php so I cant tell how this special communication will work. But why you dont use php as CGIs only and avoid using bash?

Comment: It works fine individually in Python (locally) and bash (remotely via webpage). My question is how can i get a website user communicate with the program running in python.  Sorry, I'm just getting started with these, so may have missed your point about php.

Comment: I can show you how to cummunicate via web and bash script (cgi), if that is what you want. I cant show you how to use your player nor python. If you already had a working local app why dont edit it and make it cgi ?.. so you dont need to learn bash or other programming languages.

Comment: Actually, all i want to know is, if it is possible to communicate via web with a player / program that was launched locally (not via web).

Comment: open a shell and tip the following in it... `netstat -tulpen`, then search for the service that you want to connect to. If its in there you can connect to it via those ports. Maybe you have to run the command as root, to get the service names not covert.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not a TCP/UDP service. Its a simple python program. I think i'll just revert to os.system rather than Popen.